# Update rsync to 3.1.1

Tags: versions, rsync

I've noticed that the latest version of `rsync` is actually 3.1.1, but only 3.1.0 seems to be included in 14.04.1. How can I update to the latest version?

Comment: There's no PPA available. So you'll have to compile it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source tar is available here: [rsync-3.1.1.tar.gz](http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/src/rsync-3.1.1.tar.gz) ([signature](http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/src/rsync-3.1.1.tar.gz.asc)), with a tar file of the "patches" directory now released in a separate file: [rsync-patches-3.1.1.tar.gz](http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/src/rsync-patches-3.1.1.tar.gz) ([signature](http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/src/rsync-patches-3.1.1.tar.gz.asc)). [From official site](http://rsync.samba.org/)

In Readme file you can find it.

> ### SETUP
>
> Rsync normally uses *ssh* or *rsh* for communication with remote
>   systems. It does not need to be setuid and requires no special
>   privileges for installation.  You must, however, have a working *ssh*
>   or *rsh* system. Using ssh is recommended for its security features.
>
> Alternatively, `rsync` can run in 'daemon' mode, listening on a
>   socket. This is generally used for public file distribution, although
>   authentication and access control are available.
>
> To install `rsync`, first run the `configure` script.  This will
>   create a `Makefile` and `config.h` appropriate for your system.  Then
>   type `make`.
>
> Note that on some systems you will have to force configure not to use
>   `gcc` because `gcc` may not support some features (such as 64 bit file
>   offsets) that your system may support.  Set the environment variable
>   CC to the name of your native compiler before running configure in
>   this case.
>
> Once built put a copy of `rsync` in your search path on the local and
>   remote systems (or use `make install`).  That's it!

Or From https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rsync

Comment: I'm somewhat of a newbie. How would I compile and install these?

Comment: @user260467 https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b0e16e7301dfa71b8265331d0011d21f